# Tests/Scenarios not getting executed using testng Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

Getting the below output after executing a test from TestNG runner class(Testng-Cucumber) But no tests are getting executed-

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
PASSED: runScenario("Positive Test of Purchasing the Order", "Purchase the order from eCommerce website")
Runs Cucumber Scenarios

## ===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

## ===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

It is recognizing 1 test as expected but it is not getting executed

Please Note - TestNG and Cucumber plugins for eclipse are already installed

Please find the below code -

TesNgTestRunner.java -

```
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/cucumber"}, glue = {
        "rahulshettyacademy.stepdefinitions"}, monochrome = true, plugin = {
        "html:target/cucumber.html" })
public class TestNGTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

I have tried both entering and removing "{}" in glue and features but no luck

StepDefinitionImpl.java -

```
package rahulshettyacademy.stepdefinitions;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import rahulshettyacademy.TestComponents.BaseTests;
import rahulshettyacademy.pageobjects.LandingPage;
import rahulshettyacademy.pageobjects.MyCartPage;
import rahulshettyacademy.pageobjects.PaymentPage;
import rahulshettyacademy.pageobjects.ProductCatalog;
import rahulshettyacademy.pageobjects.ThankYouPage;

public class StepDefinitionImpl extends BaseTests{
    
    public LandingPage landingPage;
    public ProductCatalog productCatalog;
    public ThankYouPage thankYouPage;
    public PaymentPage paymentPage;
    public MyCartPage myCartPage;
    
    @Given("^I Landed on eCommerce page$")
    public void landedOnECommercePage() throws IOException{
        landingPage=launchApplication();
    }
    @Given("^Logged in with (.+) and (.+)$")
    public void login(String username, String password) {
        productCatalog=landingPage.loginApplication(username,password);
    }
    @When("^I Add product (.+) to cart$")
    public void addProductToCart(String productName) {
        List<WebElement> products=productCatalog.getProductList();
        productCatalog.addProductToCart(productName);
    }
    @When("^Checkout (.+) and submit the order$")
    public void checkoutSubmitOrder(String productName) throws InterruptedException {
        myCartPage=productCatalog.goToCartPage();
        Boolean match=myCartPage.verifyProductPresent(productName);
        Assert.assertTrue(match);
        
        paymentPage=myCartPage.goToCheckout();
        paymentPage.selectCountry(driver,"india");
        thankYouPage=paymentPage.clickSubmitButton(driver);
    }
    @Then("{string} is displayed on ConfirmationPage")
    public void messageDisplayedConfirmationPage(String string) throws InterruptedException {
        String confMessage=thankYouPage.getConfMessage();
        Assert.assertTrue(confMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(string));
    }
}
```

Tried to use "{string}" instead of (.+) but no luck.
Tried with and without "^" in the beginning of each step but no luck
Tried with and without "$" sign in the end but no luck.

PurchaseOrder.feature -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VxfM.png)

POM.xml -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENAyF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVv8q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqPiw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfoOM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAwo2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XcHg.png)

Comment: Please check the images attached for pom.xml and .feature file. I couldn't paste the code here due to formatting issues.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: Als, it looks like your test suite is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your StepDefinitionImpl class extends the BaseTests class which is located under the different package. Please make sure that the package 'rahulshettyacademy.TestComponents' is included to the 'glue' in the @CucumberOptions annotation for the TestNGTestRunner class.

**!EDIT!**

Also, you are using ":" after the keywords Given/When/Then. This stops cucumber from recognizing the keywords, hence you basically have an 'empty' scenario. 
Another point is that you have an 'Examples' section for the 'Scenario', it won't work. To use Examples you have to use the 'Scenario Outline' keyword.
[More info in the official docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/)

Comment: Not working even after including the package 'rahulshettyacademy.TestComponents' in the 'glue' -

Comment: package cucumber;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(features = { "src/test/java/cucumber" }, glue = { "rahulshettyacademy.stepdefinitions",
  "rahulshettyacademy.TestComponents" }, monochrome = true, plugin = { "html:target/cucumber.html" })
public class TestNGTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}

Comment: Aw, I see, it's in your .feature file (missed that screenshot at first)
You are using ":" after the keywords Given/When/Then. This stops cucumber from recognizing the keywords, hence you basically have an 'empty' scenario.
You may still need to have the TestComponents in glue, in case you are using @Before/@After hooks.
Another point is that you have an 'Examples' section for the 'Scenario', it won't work.
To use Examples you have to use the 'Scenario Outline' keyword.

I'll edit the answer to include this info.

Comment: Thank you @sashkins. It worked after I removed ":" after the keywords Given/When/Then. Also I had to change "Scenario" with "Scenario Outline".

Comment: ErrorValidations.feature -

Scenario Outline: Error Validation
  Given I Landed on eCommerce page
  When Logged in with <username> and <password>
  Then "Incorrect email or password." message is displayed
    
    Examples: 
      | username  | password |
      | idontcre@gmail.com | Abcde@123 |

Comment: PurchaseOrder.feature -

Background:
Given I Landed on eCommerce page

  @Regression
  Scenario: Positive Test of Purchasing the Order
  Given Logged in with <username> and <password>
  When I Add product <productName> to cart
  And Checkout <productName> and submit the order
  Then "THANKYOU FOR THE ORDER." is displayed on ConfirmationPage
    
    Examples: 
      | username  | password | productName |
      | idontcare@gmail.com | Abcde@123 | IPHONE 13 PRO|